# How to search in Enterprise Architect from an Excel worksheet?

Tags: jscript, enterprise-architect

I'm a trainee and my boss asked me to make a script that searches for packages in Enterprise Architect from a name. The base is in Excel and count all the use-cases, the count I already did, but the search I could not get yet.

*edit: the count im already made, but i need a search metod, get all names from a excel file and searchs this names on Ea

Comment: you want to count all the use-cases of a specific name? In the xls file or directly in the ea project?

Comment: Does EA have an API you can access? Or can you automate an export from it, so it can be queried in some fashion? Or does it have an internal scripting language?

Comment: @halfer from what I understand from this question, EA already has a simple search function that does what he requests

Comment: the count im already made, but i need a serach metod, get all names from a excel file and searchs this names on Ea

Comment: edit the question with this info

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the ActiveX Object functionality with Jscript in EA, basicaly you can open the excel sheet directly from your script and read the data

[ActiveX Object Jscript Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6958xykx(v=vs.100).aspx)

[ActiveXObject in Sparx EA](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/script_editors.html)

> VBScript, JScript and Javascript can each create and work with ActiveX
>   / COM objects. This can help you to work with external libraries, or
>   to interact with other applications external to Enterprise Architect.
>   For example, the Scripting.FileSystemObject Class can be used to read
>   and write files on the local machine. The syntax for creating a new
>   object varies slightly for each language, as illustrated by these
>   examples:
>
> VBScript:
>
> set fsObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>
> JScript:
>
> fsObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
>
> Javascript:
>
> fsObject = new COMObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

Note: from my personal experience, this doesn't work with a JavaScript script, use Jscript or VBscript

Comment: Thanks, i will try to learn about it, but and the search metod , any help?